# aspx submit form error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im working with asp.net  framework 4.0 and I have this code:

form id="form1" runat="server" method="get" action="Profile.aspx"

```
 // some code
```

asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit"

Each time i click the submit button i get this error:

**Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.**

any idea how to fix it ???

Comment: Are you running this in a web farm or cluster?

Comment: Are any of the preconditions mentioned here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx met?

Comment: @Oded.. no
@Sweko : i checked the link before and it didnt help me

Comment: Are you changing any form values through javascript? In particular the __viewstate hidden form field?

Comment: Do you by any chance submit to a page (Profile.aspx) different than the page the form is on?

Comment: I only have asp validators on the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by cross-page POST (i.e. you are submitting the ViewState of the first page to the second). You can add PostBackUrl to the button like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx" />
```

Alternatively you can handle the click event of the button in the first page, move some of the logic in this handler and do a Response.Redirect (i.e. GET request) to the second page. The right solution depends on your particular case.

Comment: i just created a javascript and created a new form..and i submitted the new form..it worked...ill try now the postbackurl...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send post back to your current page, remove in form tag method="get" action="Profile.aspx" attributes. And handle in codebehind post data from your page.

If your want to send data you another page like Profile.aspx, use PostBackUrl attribute of the button control, like **Stilgar** wrote for you. And then in Profile.aspx codebehind to get access to control from your current page use somethink like this:

```
If(Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    var textBox = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("ControlID") as TextBox;
    if(textBox != null)
    {
        //Use your logic here
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for you!

Best regards, Dima.